# List of files - Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the list o files in any directory, in this case, the downloads directory. My app crash when I try it. Any ideas?

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File [] files = path.listFiles();
    for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        Log.d("Files",files[i].getName());
```

Comment: Can you share the logcat output on the crash? That'd be helpful

Comment: Missing Permission in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you added the permissions element in you manifest file, here is how you do it:

```
<manifest
    // other stuff here
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> // where you ask android to give you permission to it's file system
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to the android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```